# GeoServer/GeoWebCache with C#

Tags: geoserver, c#, wms, wfs, wps

I'm starting a project in which I intend to use GeoServer/GeoWebCache as a provider of WFS, WMS, WCS, and WPS services. I've configured the GeoServer to use PostGIS for storage. The frontend is using OpenLayers.

I, however, would like to use C# to program my business logic and to send requests for WMS, WFS, WCS and WPS services. I then make the response available to my view layer using View Model. I've been looking for materials that explain how this can be achieved, but no success so far. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you chose GeoServer?  I would think the C# MapScript for MapServer might be an easier route to take as GeoServer is Java based...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, user890. I have used GeoServer before, and I've gotten used to it. I haven't used MapServer before. I also tend to think that given that WMS, WFS, etc, are OGC standards, they would be app language independent. Plus the fact that GeoServer has a REST API. I also have particular expertise in Java, so that is not an issue. But there is an overriding business case to use C# in this project.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for security at the data layer, you could build a proxy in C # through which you make requests WFS / WMS from the server side so you can process the response and verify compliance with business rules, this would take a lot of work. You could also build REST service in C # that will attend to check whether the user can access the information, so that the client side be in charge of using the service before displaying the information.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/) would fit your needs. Unfortunately for you, GeoTools is a Java based solution.

[IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) might give the [Java/.NET interoperability](http://www.ikvm.net/devguide/net2java.html) you would need in case you used GeoTools.